# Search for the word and exporting 35characters after that word using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file `input.txt` which have loads of weird characters, html tags and useful materials. I want to display 35 characters after the word `description` excluding weird characters like `$$#$#@$#@***$#` and without html tags in the new file output.txt. Help me.
Thanx in advance.

My final goal is to find the word description and print 35 characters after description which shouldn't include the html tags and weird characters. Is it possible? Like here:

```
<description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;img class="float_right"
 src="http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/502ab0036bb3f7147b00000f-400-300/dnu.jpg"
 border="0" alt="dnu" width="400" height="300" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;The lawn
 was filled with &lt;a class="hidden_link"
 href="http://www.businessinsider.com/blackboard/goldman-sachs"&gt;Goldman
 Sachs&lt;/a&gt; Group Inc. partners dressed in pink looking out on a pink sunset.
```

I want to start from: `The lawn is filled with` (again skip those tags and continue from) `Group Inc. partners` (35 characters .done!) and then stop and search for another description!

Comment: Could you give a (large) example of your data? This allows us to easily see if, for example, `description` can occur multiple times in 1 line. Also do you want the first 35 characters excluding the 'weird' characters (thus potentially returning less then 35 characters) or do you want the first 35 non-weird characters.

Comment: @Sicco: Here's a sample data: 
title>Here's How A Hamptons Fundraiser Works</title><link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/businessinsider/~3/Sn8nE0mWfNo/how-a-hamptons-fundraiser-works-2012-8</link><description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;img class="float_right" src="http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/502ab0036bb3f7147b00000f-400-300/dnu.jpg" border="0" alt="dnu" width="400" height="300" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: OK; so your question is quite different now. You have an HTML file and want to retrieve some data from the HTML. Which attribute of the `description` tag do you want to extract? Ideally you would do this using XPath or XQuery, which is the best way to retrieve data from structured HTML/XML documents.

Comment: Yea it's the source of HTML. The file extension is .txt . I don't care which attributes description carry. But while extract characters those tags and weird characters shouldn't be included 1) Search for word description
2) Extract 35 characters after description excluding those weird characters and html tags
3) Redirect output to output.txt
Please help me!!

Comment: Those 'weird' characters are [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). Once interpreted its reads: `<description><p><img class="float_right`. Could you be more specific and tell us what your **final** goal is? What do you want to achieve? If you just delete the HTML entities, then your HTML will be corrupt.

Comment: I have updated the question again. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the text within an HTML node using XPath. In your case this should work:

```
xpath -q -e '//description//text()' input.txt
```

The query `//description//text()` works as follows:

- `//description`: drill down the HTML document till you find a node named `description`
- `//text()`: within this node drill down all other nodes and select their text

Given your data this outputs:

```
The lawn was filled with 
Goldman Sachs
 Group Inc. partners dressed in pink looking out on a pink sunset.
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added the sample. And, finally to redirect the output to output.txt >> output.txt would work, rite?
Thank you!

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Debian and can't seem to install it!

Comment: I would like to accomplish by result using sed and grep command. You mentioned that command before. But you edited with xpath. Can you please provide me the yesterday's command. 
Thank you!

Comment: I still strongly recommend using XPath as this is both the easiest and optimal way to parse HTML (your question to use regex in the form of `grep`/`sed` is [not the first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) on SO). You can [easily install the XPath command](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxml-xpath-perl/libxml-xpath-perl_1.13-7_all.deb) (which in itself is a simple `Perl` wrapper) and then use the above code.

Comment: Thank you! Also, can u give the yesterday's sed and grep command? PLeaseee I will use that as a reference in other scripts. PLease..

Comment: Stack Overflow is like a Wiki, so all edits are saved. Click on the `edited <time> ago` link beneath my post to see its history.

Comment: Also, if you think my answer solved your question then you can accept if my ticking the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: Hey i installed the xpath and ran the command but the output is same as my script file. Also, the ran the previous command, the output is same as my script file.

Comment: Could you put your whole HTML into a code block in your post or on pastebin.com, so I can test it on all your data.

Comment: Finally this command worked!! sed -r 's/.*description>//g; s/&lt;[^&]*&gt;//g; s/(.{35}).*/\1/ ' input.txt Thank you for your effort.